# magento - custom option price in cart

Tags: magento, cart

I have products that have custom options each of them having different pricing.
Currently, Magento combines the product price with the custom option price and shows it already calculated as the product price on the shopping cart.

Instead, I would like to show the original product price, and then the corresponding custom option prices below on the shopping cart.

I have found the relevant template file, and it uses `getOptionList()` to get the custom options.  However, the optionList does not contain details for the sku or price. The same with `getProductOptions()`.

Any suggestions on how to get this data on the cart template?

Answer (score 2):

Open up your template file

**app/design/frontend/default/theme/template/checkout/cart/item/default.phtml**

Find the foreach loop:

```
<?php foreach ($_options as $_option) : ?>
```

Within that foreach loop, add this code:

```
<?php

        $optionId = $_option['option_id'];
        $product = $_item->getProduct();
        $option = $product->getOptionById($optionId);
        $itemOption = $_item->getOptionByCode('option_' . $option->getId());
        $price = false;
        foreach ($option->getValues() as $values) {
            if ($values->getId() == $itemOption['value']) {
                $price = $values->price;
            }
        }
        if ($price !== false) {
            echo Mage::helper('core')->currency($price);
        }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend setting up custom options for the product itself, which allow you to adjust the price according to the option that is selected.  This will allow the customer to select they option that they want and see the price adjustment on the product page.

Here is a video about it from the Magento blog: http://www.magentocommerce.com/blog/video-custom-product-options-in-magento-11/

Comment: This is exactly how I'm setting up the custom options.  However, as you can see on the last frame of the video, the shopping cart adds the $15 monogram fee into the $30 product price and displays it as $45.  Instead, I need to separate out the view on the shopping cart page so it shows the product as $30 and the monogram as $15.

Comment: Gotcha, not 100% on that then, sorry